# ng-model is not working for multiselect dropdown in angular Js after chrome update to version 95.0

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-directive, google-chrome-devtools

I Have used below line of code for multi selection. I am trying to multiselect on one entity but as soon as the scope is passed on to the next entity, the elements that I have selected in first entity gets unselected-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbriJ.png)

This is working fine on previous versions of chrome but not in 95.0

Answer (score 0):

This is breaking because you're setting `ng-model` to the same property that `ng-options` is using. So the moment you select something, `abcDTO.SelectionTypes` gets reset to whatever you selected. `ng-options` and `ng-model` should never be set to the same property. Has nothing to do with the Chrome version.

[Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-gfzaxy?file=home/home.html) of it working once you change `ng-model` to something else.

```html
<select
  multiple="multiple" ng-multiple="true" rows="10" size="4"
  ng-model="abcDTO.Selection"
  ng-options="x.SelectionID as x.SelectionDesc for x in abcDTO.SelectionTypes">
</select>
```

Comment: I tried that also by binding the same to different objects but it did not work. Whereas this is working on Mozilla and IE but not in Chrome post the update

Comment: @amarshubhanker I can take another look, but you will need to post a demo reproducing this issue. https://stackblitz.com/fork/angularjs